# Missing biometric info from US Passport

Tags: usa, children, global-entry, biometric-passports

My daughter has the US Global Entry but since we have obtained a passport for her as a baby she's missing biometric information.

How does one go about getting the passport with the biometric information or adding the biometric info to her unexpired existing passport?

Comment: What biometric information are you seeking to add?  As far as I'm aware, the only biometric data in a US passport is a digitized copy of the passport photo.  Does hers lack that?

Comment: Yes.  When going through the Global Entry Kiosk the Kiosk spits out a message: No Biometric information.  Prints a blank ticket and sends us to a human to cross the border.

Comment: How old is she now?  My guess is that you simply have to renew the passport via the usual process.  But it may be worth contacting the Global Entry people to ask if they have other suggestions.

Comment: 3.5. Still has about 2 years left of passport validity

Comment: Did you ask the border control agent? Or just drop a Global Entry office and ask as a walk-in what is going on.

Comment: @RoboKaren You can only get into Global Entry Office by appointment.  Border Control agent said that you can add biometrics but not how it is done

Comment: @Karlson got it. I’ve done walkins to update my info (new passport) for Global Entry.

Comment: AFAIK you'll need a new passport. You can't just add a chip to a passport that never had one.

Comment: Are you sure that her photo is not biometric? **Since August 2007, the U.S. has been issuing only e-passports**. I assume that the chip in the passport is not working.

Comment: @Karlson in regards to latest comment above?

Comment: Chip is working. It contains no info.

Comment: If you have an Android phone you can use the app [ReadID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.innovalor.nfciddocshowcase) to check what the chip contains. It works very well and I've used it many times when signing agreements with people to check their ID validity.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you have two options: renew the child's passport or apply for a second passport for the child. There is no restriction on renewing a passport early, so that is probably the cleanest option. The U.S. State Department provides second passports for situations where you need two passports. The second passport has a shorter validity period. I don't know if a second passport would contain biometric information if the original passport doesn't, or if children are eligible.